# Linq to SQL - Audit Trail (find old values in SubmitChanges)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, entity, audit-trail

At the moment I'm looking for a way to find the old values of an entity in the [context].SubmitChanges().

As far as I can tell only the new values show up.
Do I really need to do a query to the database to get the old values of the entity?

The solution by [GertArnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gertarnold):

```
    public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
                {
                    // Get the changeset
                    ChangeSet changeSet = this.GetChangeSet();

                    // Put the updated objects into a IEnumerable
                    IEnumerable<object> updatedEntities = changeSet.Updates;

                    foreach (var entity in updatedEntities.Where(entity => AuditTypes.Contains(entity.GetType())))
                    {
                        var old = this.GetTable(entity.GetType()).GetModifiedMembers(entity);
                        // Do something with the old values
                    }

                    // Save the changes
                    base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to SQL: getting old values of changed rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852533/linq-to-sql-getting-old-values-of-changed-rows)

Comment: @WouterdeKort I saw the post indeed but it doesn't state how to get the cache. Also when I look into my SubmitChanges I see the new values, even without calling the refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the [Table.GetModifiedMembers method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534359.aspx).

As you want old values of *an* entity, this method is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link.

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/05/08/linq-to-sql-audit-trail.aspx

You have your answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/4498dddb-6dc2-4676-ba0a-eeda1aa453b0

Comment: I already found that link on google, although we don't want to use thirdparty libraries for the solution.

Comment: Your second link would make me change all the entities. This is not the thing I would like to do. Thanks for the response but I really need a way to get the old values. And if this is not possible then I would like to know this also.